# What are the details about Vayu dev?

Tags: vedas, vayu, vayupurana

How was Vayu dev born ? Why was he given birth ? Who are his parents ? Any details about him ? I think he is considered as physically very strong .

What are the details about him ? What is his puprose ? What work does he do ?